# Getting values of a field that appear in documents with at least two unique values of another field

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to get the unique values of a field, that appears in documents with at least 2 different values of another field.
E.g., if I have a document per book bought with a mapping like this:

```
buyer_name: keyword  # john_doe
book: keyword  # ISBN
```

I'd like to get all buyers that bought at least two different books. Any efficient way to do this? Can this be feasible for millions of unique names that exist in the DB - by using some client, or with the async search perhaps?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand - you want to do an analog of sub select in SQL based languages.

But unfortunately - they are not supported in Elasticsearch.
Probably it can be done by 2 requests using bucket aggregation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html

You can try something like this query, and then take ids of accounts that contain more then 2 doc_counts.

```
{
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"aggs": {
    "buyer": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "buyer_name"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "unique_books": {
                "cardinality": {
                    "field": "book"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Or you can try to play with search script counting unique values. But can`t guarantee the performance of that thing.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used it as a base. I've replaced the terms aggregation with a composite aggregation, as there are many unique buyers, and I couldn't create a separate bucket for each, and used a bucket_selector for filtering the aggregation results (no need for two queries).